# How can I update ubuntu to kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu

I have ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed. I want to completely update my ubuntu copy to kubuntu using cd image

Comment: What do you mean by "completely update"? You can either install kubuntu-desktop, or backup and do a clean kubuntu install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Kubuntu install CD works just like Ubuntu's (in my experience). You should be given the option to keep your data intact, while upgrading the the System files. Of course this depends on how your system is setup. *If you use disk encryption, you may not be presented with this option.*

Kubuntu can alternatively be setup on your system without an install CD, by adding the `kubuntu-desktop` packages, while leaving the vanilla Ubuntu system mostly unchanged. *This may be a better option if your disks are encrypted.*

In a terminal, type:
`sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`
Then choose Kubuntu as your desktop environment at login.

---

Optionally, if you wish to remove the Gnome Desktop Environment (ubuntu's default) and make KDE your default, You can install Kate desktop manager with:
`sudo apt install kdm`

then remove the Gnome desktop manager:
`sudo apt remove gdm`

and finally, set KDM as your default desktop manager with:
`dpkg reconfigure kdm`